# Dumping json file in python

Tags: python, json, dump

I extract from authenticated API as follow:

```
Event_data = requests.get(url_Event,auth = (user,password)).json()
```

I want to save this as json file and I tried as follow:

```
filename = 'Event'+str(Match_ID [f])
with open(filename) as outfile:
        json.dump(Event_data,outfile)
```

It showed the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Event2735717'
```

My API call is in loop and filename is string ('Event2735717')

How can I save a json file for each loop call from API.
Your advice will be much appreciated
Thanks,

Zep.

Comment: This isn't a JSON problem; you are opening a file for **reading**, and in that case the file must exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open the file for writing by passing `'w'` as the `mode` parameter for `open`:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
```

The file is otherwise opened for reading only by default and would raise the  exception in question if the file does not already exist.

Comment: I did try with 'w' too

Comment: @Zephyr: so what happened when you used `'w'` as the mode? Please do state that *in your question*.

Comment: @Zephyr Then it is likely that your `filename` includes a path name that does not already exist. Please make sure that all directories specified by the path name exist.

Comment: It worked. I used cap W. That's why I tried other way.Thanks a lot